# HAPI Fhir: Searching by identifier with a particular code

Tags: search, identifier, hl7-fhir, hapi

I want to retrieve the procedure having an identifier with value 2266 and type.coding.code of "RI"

The identifier part of the procedure looks like this:

```
"identifier": [
          {
            "use": "usual",
            "type": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
                  "code": "RI"
                }
              ],
              "text": "RI"
            },
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
            "value": "2266"
          },
          {
            "use": "usual",
            "type": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
                  "code": "PLAC"
                }
              ],
              "text": "PLAC"
            },
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
            "value": "procId69"
          }
        ],
```

Searching with:

```
Procedure?identifier=2266
```

return the procedure, but I cant be sure that it has the correct code.

Referring to the search doc https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#token I tried

```
Procedure?identifier:of-type=http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203|RI|2266
```

But it doesn't work for me, nothing is returned. Whats the correct syntax for the query ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your of-type syntax is correct.  Are you sure the server in question supports the of-type qualifier?  (It's a new capability and not a lot of servers support it yet.)

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. Seems to be not supported by HAPI 4.0 yet